# Device or resource busy--when to change the device's label

Tags: disk

I want to change `/dev/sda1` 's name as `debian-11.05` with command:

```
sudo exfatlabel   /dev/sda1  debian-11.05
exfatprogs version : 1.1.0
open failed : /dev/sda1, Device or resource busy
```

How to fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

The device is probably mounted, you need to unmount it first. Some filesystems (like ext4) can be relabeled when mounted, but not exFAT.